# How to assign value to SQL variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have SQL code where I am assigning the output of the nested query to a variable but gets error incorrect syntax near )

Below is code:

```
set @MAX_CNT =(select coun from (select MAX(SEQ) Coun from (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY COUNTRY)SEQ,*  FROM #TEMP1
)xx)y)
```

Error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Not Sure what is the problem

```
set @MAX_CNT =(select coun from (select MAX(SEQ) Coun from (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY COUNTRY)SEQ,*  FROM #TEMP1
)xx)y)
```

It should assign the value to variable.

Comment: It works for me. Post your full code please. Make sure that that's the line of the error (error message states line 53 but error can be before, like missing and `END` of a `CASE`.).

Comment: Use SELECT instead of SET. This will assign the value to the variable. But the best way is answered by @Gordon Linoff below.

Comment: Your query seems to be valid. Since the error message whines about an error on line 53 and you only have 3 lines in your posted code, I assume you have not posted the entire script and the error actually applies to some other SQL fragment (not shown here)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @MAX_CNT = (select MAX(SEQ) Coun from 
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY id)SEQ, *  FROM users
) xx)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just write this?

```
select @MAX_CNT = count(*)
from #temp1;
```

Using window functions with aggregation is not needed.

Comment: Fixed it...i was missing END for Begin in sql